# Чистка DOM элемента по таймауту

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

Приведенная ниже функция чистит потихонечку все содержимое родителя, вызываясь через небольшие промежутки времени и очищая 10 строк. Она используется только при количестве строк более определенного значения, так как если удалять все разом, браузер подвешивается на несколько секунд. Пока чистится данный объект, система работает с новым созданным в этой же функции.

```
myFunction = function() {

    // скрываем панель
    var myPanel = document.getElementById('my-panel');
    myPanel.className = 'panel hide';
    myPanel.removeAttribute('id');
    var myPanelParent = myPanel.parentNode;

    // удал€ем все id внутри элемента
    var nodes = myPanel.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].removeAttribute('id');
    }

    // создаем другую аналогичную панель
    $(myPanelParent).append($('<div id="my-panel"></div>'));

    // внутри первой панели удаляем все строки
    var myRemove = function() {
        var myRemoveCnt = 10; // сколько элементов удаляем
        var myCurentEl = 0;
        while (myCurentEl < myRemoveCnt) {
            var myTrEl = myEl.querySelector('tr');
            if (myTrEl !== null) {
                myEl.removeChild(myTrEl);
            } else { // если элементов для удаления больше нет
                myPanel.parentNode.removeChild(myPanel); // удаляем наконец сам элемент с остатком содержимого
                myCurentEl = myRemoveCnt;
                return;
            }
            myCurentEl++;
        }
        setTimeout(myRemove, 10); // перезапускаем каждые 0.01сек
    };
    myRemove(); // запускаем удаление
};
```

Проблема в том, что в консоль при таком подходе выводится ошибка на строке `myPanel.parentNode.removeChild(myPanel);` о том, что скрипт не может найти родителя для элемента, то есть что `parentNode` не определен. Почему скрипт падает и почему только одна ошибка вызывается (скрипт ведь выполняется довольно много раз) не могу разобраться.

Сперва думал, что элемент отвязывается от дерева и родительский элемент теряется (в дебаге у `myPanel` значение `parentNode` теряется) поменял код на `myPanelParent.removeChild(myPanel);` но ситуацию это не спасло, стало ругаться на то, что нет дочерних элементов у объекта.

Comment: `var myTrEl = myEl.querySelector('tr');` ни где не нашел в вашем коде инициализацию переменной myEL +  желательно бы html код

Comment: вырезал лишнее из кода не заметил.... myEl это таблица внутри элемента myPanel в которую и вставляются строки.

Answer (score 1):

а мне кажется просто

```
myPanel.remove()
```

непонятно зачем искать родителя, если можно просто удалить

Comment: такой код, к сожалению подвешивает браузер на пару-тройку секунд в зависимости от количества элементов внутри myPanel

Comment: Сперва написал, что ваш код не подходит и есть куда более быстрые варианты, но потом вспомнил, что я удаляю уже почти пустой объект с парой-тройкой вложенных и наверное это хорошая идея. Проверю при первом же доступе к тестовому серверу

Comment: в IE 10 не работает, к сожалению, а в jquery также удаляет через обращение к родительскому элементу... попробую подебажить, может при определении объекта через jquery связь с родителем не потеряется, на что я мало надеюсь

Comment: ИЕ всегда боль. Прошу прощения, давно уже с ним не работал :)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:
myPanel.removeFromParent();

Comment: мне кажется или это больше к java относится

Answer (score 0):

Ну открепили вы один раз myPanel от общего dom-дерева, myPanel остался без родителя,
откуда должен взяться родитель при повторной попытке это сделать? Насколько я вижу, переменная myPanel нигде не переопределяется

Comment: она и не должна переопределяться в пределах одной функции, определяется при запуске этой самой функции и все, затем только очищается. Интересен тот момент, что по идее от DOM элемент не должен отвязываться. Ну удалил я ему id, классы заменил но его связи внутри DOM должны остаться. Я специально искал материалы где было бы указано при каких обстоятельствах  идет отвязывание элемента, но там только пара специализированных функций и все и здесь у элемента должен быть виден родитель. Разве что в замыкание передается новый объект, а не ссылка на DOM

Comment: Ещё раз. `myPanel.parentNode.removeChild(myPanel)` - после выполнения этой строчки элемент myPanel будет отделен от дом-дерева и останется "висеть" сам по себе, без родителя. Когда исполнение кода второй раз сюда попадает, у myPanel уже нет родителя и это вызывает ошибку.

Comment: **но его связи внутри DOM должны остаться** - не должны. Манипуляции с дом как раз нужны для того, чтобы менять связи между узлами, и в вашем коде вы открепляете узел от общего дерева

Comment: как раз 'myPanel.parentNode.removeChild(myPanel)' выполнится только в том случае, если все строки в таблице мы уже потерли и далее мы выходим из функции по ретурну, то есть еще раз после удаления элемента она уже не запустится

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNode(n) {
    if(typeof n=='string') 
        n=document.getElementById(n);
    return n;
}
function delNode(n) {
    n=getNode(n);
    if(typeof(n.remove)=="function") 
        n.remove();
    else 
        n.parentNode.removeChild(n); // IE 11-
}
```

`delNode("IdName")` - удаляет "узел" и все его дочерние "узлы".